# Test written for django URL Dispatcher not working

Tags: python, django, testing, http-status-code-404

I'm working on a simple webservice in django.  This is my first web app in django/python so I wouldn't be surprised if I'm missing something obvious here, but...

I'm currently trying to test my logic for filtering a url.

```
            # Works as expected
            response = self.client.post("/mysite/goodurl/")
            self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

            # Has an exception rather than a 404
            response = self.client.post("/mysite/badurl/")
            self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 404)
```

So, the `badurl` case isn't simply being not found and throwing a 404, instead I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/me/mysite/tests.py", line 55, in test_add_tracker
    response = self.client.post("/mysite/badurl/")
  File "/home/path/to/some/bin/dir/freeware/Python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 449, in post
    response = super(Client, self).post(path, data=data, content_type=content_type, **extra)
  File "/home/path/to/some/bin/dir/freeware/Python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 262, in post
    return self.request(**r)
  File "/home/path/to/some/bin/dir/freeware/Python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 111, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/path/to/some/bin/dir/freeware/Python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 77, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: EtimeFetcher() got an unexpected keyword argument 'alias'
```

I've tried googling for the EtimeFetcher message, but no luck.  Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have some view to catch all Http404 errors? It seems that Django however had found a view to execute for the badurl. Search in your code for statements containing the alias named parameter, like: "alias=yyyy". Or probably some url pattern, contaning 'alias' as extra parameter in urls.py ?

Comment: @Tisho - you were right.  Please put your comment as an answer so I can upvote/accept.  Basically, I had a url mapped to a view I hadn't written yet.  When the request handler was trying to go through all of the views on the url list, it went to the one I had yet to write...and boom!

Comment: Nice to hear that it helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uou may probably have some view to catch all Http404 errors. It seems that Django however had found a view to execute for the /badurl. Search in your code for statements containing the alias named parameter, like: "alias=yyyy". Or probably some url pattern, contaning 'alias' as extra parameter in urls.py?